# What does def main () -> None do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I am working through Mastering Matplotlib and in chapter two they introduce the following code snippet:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.4
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main () -> None:
    plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
    plt.ylabel('some numbers')
    plt.savefig('simple-line.png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This can be seen in [this](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/masteringmatplotlib/architecture/blob/master/notebooks/mmpl-arch.ipynb) notebook, cell 10. I have never seen a main method defined this way, what is the function of `-> None`? 
My only thought so far is that this may be similar to `def main(argv=None)`?

Beyond that, what is `->` in Python? I can't find it in [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm) list of Python operators.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html
It's a type hint for the return type of the function.

Comment: It is similar to creating a `void` function in Java.  It is python's way of starting to incorporate types in to make the language more robust.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

As is, it does absolutely nothing. It is a type annotation for the `main` function that simply states that this function returns `None`. Type annotations were introduced in `Python 3.5` and are specified in [`PEP 484`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Annotations for the return value of a function use the symbol `->` followed by a type. It is completely optional and if you removed it, nothing would change.

This will have *absolutely no effect on execution*, it is only taken under consideration if you use it with a type checking tool like [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/).

Comment: so it's possible to turn python scripts into partially, statically typed programs which will be faster than the regular, dynamically typed python? if yes, is it a big difference? should I familiarise myself with this if I run data analysis on large data sets?